# Site specific config in Symfony application

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have an application in Symfony 3.4 that serves on some different domains which may have specific supported languages. According to a domain/language combination there is specific config that should be applied across application in different places.

My question is: how to properly apply this config that can be used in different application services?

The 'spirit' of this kind of config points me to parameters that are easily reused in Symfony app. However question is still there - how to make them kind of dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found a solution. You'll need to use [Symfony's capability to construct external parameters in PHP file](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/external_parameters.html#miscellaneous-configuration).

So first you need to add this to your `config.yml` file:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: site.php }
```

In `app/config/site.php` you will have something like this:

```
<?php

if (substr_compare($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'mybrand.nl', -strlen('mybrand.nl')) === 0) {
    $container->setParameter('site.brand', 'mybrand');
    $container->setParameter('site.language', 'nl');
}
```

And then somewhere in your app you are able to use defined parameter `$this->getParameter('site.brand')` or in services configuration `%site.brand%`.

Beware that you won't have all the useful Symfony services and such in that PHP file - only bare PHP internals, globals and so on. Also keep in mind that `site.php` will be executed on each request - don't do anything heavy in it or this will impact performance of your entire application.